# Converter does not seem to be used when component has a renderer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, renderer

As known, we can easily write our custom conveter and register it to the component as follows:

```
<f:converter converterId="cId" />
```

or

```
<f:converter binding="#{mybean}" />
```

depneds on our needs. But now consider the source code of `UIInput` that's responsible for the exact conversion (comments ommited):

```
 protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context,
                                       Object newSubmittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        Renderer renderer = getRenderer(context);
        Object newValue;

        if (renderer != null) {
            newValue = renderer.getConvertedValue(context, this,
                 newSubmittedValue); // <----------- 1
        } else if (newSubmittedValue instanceof String) {
            Converter converter = getConverterWithType(context);
            if (converter != null) {
                newValue = converter.getAsObject(context, this,
                     (String) newSubmittedValue);// <----------- 2
            } else {
                newValue = newSubmittedValue;
            }
        } else {
            newValue = newSubmittedValue;
        }
        return newValue;
    }
```

So, it's clear that we make a choise about what converter we should use. Moreover, as far as I understand, if a component has a separated `Renderer` we can't apply our custom converter specified as a tag in a facelet (because of the `if(renderer != null){...} else if(newSubmittedValue instanceof String){...}`). For instance `<h:inputText />` the component class is `UIInput`, and also it has a custom `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer`, therfore `getRenderer(context)` returns something that's not `null`. So, we should skip the convertion specified by our `converter` tag even if we define it as

```
<h:inputText  value="#{myBean.prop}"/>
    <f:converter inding="#{bean}" />  
</h:inputText>
```

The `inputText` has a custom renderer, so the converter shouldn't do anything specified here:

```
 Converter converter = getConverterWithType(context);
 if (converter != null) {
     newValue = converter.getAsObject(context, this,
           (String) newSubmittedValue);// <----------- 2
 } else {
       newValue = newSubmittedValue;
 }
```

Couldn't you explain it? How does the conversion actually work and what's the difference between `Renderer`'s converter and our custom `converter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the renderer does the same. See also javadoc of [`Renderer#getConvertedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html#getConvertedValue-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.component.UIComponent-java.lang.Object-).

> Attempt to convert previously stored state information into an object of the type required for this component (**optionally using the registered `Converter` for this component, if there is one**). If conversion is successful, the new value should be returned from this method; if not, a `ConverterException` should be thrown.

In case of `<h:inputText>` in Mojarra, source code can be found in [`HtmlBasicInputRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java#HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjavax.faces.component.UIComponent%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).

This design allows the renderer to take full control over the conversion step and if necessary manipulate this step. Note that it's possible to declaratively (via `faces-config.xml`) override the renderer of a (standard) component without changing the component itself in the view. Also note that the term "custom renderer" in your question is not entirely right. It's just the standard renderer. We talk about a "custom renderer" only when the web application provides its own, overriding the standard one.

Comment: Ah, now I see, thank you. But isn't that confused? I presume that such a thing is some kind of legacy code when the there was no such an abstraction as `Renderer` taking over the representation of the component. So as of the Renderer was introduced we just have to preserve backward capability or something else. Is it true?

Comment: Nope, it definitely isn't legacy code. It's just a level of abstraction which already exist since JSF 1.0. It's true that most custom component Hello World examples and/or internal-only components render themselves without a renderer, but this isn't true for public implementations and component libraries. Abstracting the renderer allows us to override it without the need to change the views. This can be very useful in cases when you need to change/finetune/bugfix the actual HTML output.

Comment: Real world use cases can be found in those Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+faces-config.xml+render-kit

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonble. Got it.